# Does Stopping an IIS 7 website also stop the application pool that is associated with it?

Tags: iis, iis-7

When you right click on a website in the IIS Manager, and select stop, it disables the bindings and causes IIS to stop serving that site. When that is done, will that also stop the application pool that it is bound to, if it is the only thing using that App pool?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stopping a site does not stop the application pool associated with the site.  In fact the worker process serving the site still exists and the code loaded in the worker process still exists.

You can see this for yourself, using the HTTP.SYS NETSH extension.

```
NETSH HTTP SHOW SERVICESTATE
```

After you stop the site in IIS manager, you will still see its worker process up and the application pool running.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you :)